# LDAP can't search objects directly below root

Tags: python, ldap

I think this is a general ldap question, but I've written example code in python.

I can search for objects if I specify a dn below the 'root', but if I try to search at the top of the tree, I get an error:

```
import ldap

server = '<server address>'
realm = '<realm>'
realm_dn = ','.join(['DC=%s' % part for part in realm.lower().split('.')])

l = ldap.initialize('ldap://%s' % server)
auth_tokens = ldap.sasl.gssapi('')
l.sasl_interactive_bind_s('', auth_tokens)

system = 'CN=System,%s' % realm_dn

print('Containers at system:')
result = l.search_s(system, ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL, '(objectCategory=Container)', ['cn'])
for i in result:
    print(i[-1]['cn'])

print('Containers at top:')
result = l.search_s(realm_dn, ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL, '(objectCategory=Container)', ['cn'])
for i in result:
    print(i[-1]['cn'])
```

The first search succeeds and prints all the containers in System. I'd expect the second search to find the 'System' container (among others), but it doesn't.  Instead I get this error:

```
  File "test_ldap_search.py", line 19, in <module>
    result = l.search_s(realm_dn, ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL, '(objectCategory=Container)', ['cn'])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 831, in search_s
    return self.search_ext_s(base,scope,filterstr,attrlist,attrsonly,None,None,timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 825, in search_ext_s
    return self.result(msgid,all=1,timeout=timeout)[1]
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 717, in result
    resp_type, resp_data, resp_msgid = self.result2(msgid,all,timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 721, in result2
    resp_type, resp_data, resp_msgid, resp_ctrls = self.result3(msgid,all,timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 728, in result3
    resp_ctrl_classes=resp_ctrl_classes
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 735, in result4
    ldap_result = self._ldap_call(self._l.result4,msgid,all,timeout,add_ctrls,add_intermediates,add_extop)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 308, in _ldap_call
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 292, in _ldap_call
    result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.OPERATIONS_ERROR: {'info': u'000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906DD, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1771', 'desc': u'Operations error'}
```

I know that I'm authenticated. I've kinit'd as the Administrator. So the "In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection" message is misleading.

I've tried to search for any type of object, and it always succeeds below the root of the tree, and fails at the top. Is there some ldap-ism I'm not understanding here?

The ldap server is a Windows 2008 R2 server.

Answer (score 0):

This same search works using the python ldap3 code.

```
l = ldap3.Connection(server, user=user, password=password, authentication=ldap3.NTLM, auto_bind=True)

print('Containers at top:')
l.search(realm_dn, '(objectCategory=Container)', search_scope='LEVEL', attributes= ['cn'])
for i in l.entries:
    print(i['cn'])
```

Maybe this is a bug in the python-ldap code?